# Unable to Launch Chrome Instance in cron in Linux(ubuntu) environment. But Working fine in command prompt and python shell

Tags: linux, google-chrome, selenium, cron, selenium-chromedriver

**"Web Driver Exception: Message: chrome not reachable"**

Driver info:

chrome driver = 2.27.440175,

platform=Linux 4.4.0-47-generic x86_64

Comment: What is your cron command? Maybe you have some customization in your shell which cron does not have.